# C# project NOT being rebuilt after modifications and starting Debug

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

If I make a modification and don't explicitly tell it to rebuild, it won't. How can I get back to the old behaviour (attempt a rebuild before debug if the source was modified)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Open Configuration manager and under the active solution configuration check build checkbox.

Answer (score 10):

Under Tools/Options/Projects and Solution/Build and Run there is a Combobox titled "On run, when projects are out of date". Select "Always build".

Comment: Good to note that this is the same place where you'd turn up the verbosity for the output window when building (as building uses MSBuild).

Comment: Also note the option "Only build startup projects and dependencies on Run"

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the the project is not set to `Build` in the `Configuration Manager`.
Double check it here: Build -> Configuration Manager

Answer (score 0):

Right click on Solution-> Properties -> conf Properties, check 'build' next to the project.